# Stored procedure big where clause or multiple procedures

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

Is it better to have one big query or N small ones which will be called via code?

For example to select all the customers with multiple parameters:

```
select
   id,
   name,
   firstname,
   city,
   birthday,
   ...
from dbo.Customers
where (@Name is null or name like @Name)
and (@FirstName is null or firstname like @FirstName )
and (@City is null or city @City)
and (@Birthday is null or birthday = @Birthday)
```

Or too have multiple stored procedures like

```
select
   id,
   name,
   firstname,
   city,
   birthday,
   ...
from dbo.Customers
where (@Name is null or name like @Name)
and (@FirstName is null or firstname like @FirstName)
```

---

```
select
   id,
   name,
   firstname,
   city,
   birthday,
   ...
from dbo.Customers
where city like @City
```

---

```
select
   id,
   name,
   firstname,
   city,
   birthday,
   ...
from dbo.Customers
where  birthday = @Birthday
```

Comment: What do you mean "multiple stored procedures"?  These are queries.

Comment: First one is better. It will have one table hit

Comment: @GordonLinoff These are the select statements from the stored procedures. The small ones are xxx_GetAllByName, xxx_GetAllByCity, xxx_GetAllByBirthday and the big one xxx_GetAllByCriteria

Comment: duplicate http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93494/stored-procedure-big-where-clause-or-multiple-procedures

Answer (score 1):

If you have a small-ish table (hundreds or a few thousand rows), then one query with a complex `where` clause is fine:

```
where (@Name is null or name like @Name) and
      (@FirstName is null or firstname like @FirstName ) and
      (@City is null or city @City) and
      (@Birthday is null or birthday = @Birthday)
```

This query cannot take advantage of indexes, so it will necessarily do a full-table scan.

If you have indexes on the table and you want the query to use them, then dynamic SQL is probably the way to go:

declare @sql varchar(max);

```
set @sql = <your query here without the `where` clause>.

select @sql = ('where 1=1 and ' +
               (case when @Name is not null then 'and name like @Name' else '' end) +
               . . .
              );

exec sp_execute_sql @sql, N'@name varchar(255), @firstname varchar(255) . . . ',
     @name = @name, @firstname = @firstname, . . .;
```

This will remove the `or` conditions from the query, making it more likely to use appropriate indexes.

Comment: It might be more clear if the where clause is constructed with several if statements, for example "if (@Name is not NULL) set @sql = sql + "and name like @name"

Answer (score 1):

When you create procedure that has several optional criteria like this:

```
(@Name is null or name like @Name) and 
(@FirstName is null or firstname like @FirstName)
```

The problem is that SQL Server cannot use indexes for any fields, because query plan is created the first time it is executed and it is stored and re-used for next time.

If the table is small, the cost of clustered index scan doesn't probably matter, but if the table is big or the procedure is called often, you'll have a couple of choices:

1) Use "option (recompile)". This will make a new plan every time, and then SQL Server can eliminate criteria that wasn't given from the plan. Creating new plan every time causes extra CPU to be spent on it. If I remember correctly, this works from SQL Server 2008 onwards.

2) Create several procedures for cases when the value has been given, or separate select statements inside if-blocks in one procedure. This way the plans can be stored and re-used

3) Create dynamic SQL with variables + sp_execute_sql like in @Gordon Linoff's answer